Java failed to build .jar with Spring Boot
I try to build .jar with Spring Boot for Java8.
But,I get this message.
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '1.5.21.RELEASE'] Failed to apply plugin 'org.springframework.boot'. Configuration with name 'runtime' not found.
I didnt know what 'Configuration with name 'runtime' not found.' means.
This is my Gradle, please help me to fix it. Thanks!
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.21.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.5.21.RELEASE'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

    implementation fileTree('dir': 'libs', 'include': '*.jar')

    implementation 'org.json:json:20231013'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.11.5'
    runtimeOnly 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.11.5'
    runtimeOnly 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:0.11.5'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}



Does this answer your question? org.springframework.boot Configuration with name 'runtime' not found

This seems to happens because you are using a version of Gradle that is not support by the  Spring Boot Gradle Plugin version you are using.
You are using 1.5.21.RELEASE which supports gradle version [2.9 , 3.x],as you can see here.
As further explanation, in the Gradle version you are using, the configurations compile, testCompile, runtime and testRuntime have been replaced by implementation, testImplementation, runtimeOnly and testRuntimeOnly
Either you downgrade the Gradle version or you upgrade Spring plugin, which is what I recommend, following this announcement
